# Rendering a texture in openGL with Qt5 and glew

Tags: qt, opengl, glew

I am trying to render a textured quad in openGL using Qt5 and glew.
specifically I am using a QopenGLWidget.

The code I am using is modified from https://open.gl/textures
The main changes are using a triangle strip instead of an elements buffer
and using my own pixel array instead of loading an image.

I have tested changes and they work using glfw3.

In Qt all I can see is a black quad with no colour.
This only occurs when I try to use textures, it renders colours fine if i remove the texture part of the shader.

My shaders compile fine with no errors (although there is no error checking in the code below).

```
texture(tex, Texcoord)
```

is just outputting zero.

So my question is, why is it rendering just a black quad?

```
GLfloat tmpdata[] = {
//pos               //colour            //texCoord
-0.5f, 0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
-0.5f, -0.5f,       1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f,  // Bottom-left
0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f // Bottom-right
};

GLRenderer::GLRenderer(QWidget *parent)
    :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{
// Shader sources
VertSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec2 position;"
    "in vec3 color;"
    "in vec2 texcoord;"
    "out vec3 Color;"
    "out vec2 Texcoord;"
    "void main() {"
    "   Color = color;"
    "   Texcoord = texcoord;"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
    "}";
FragSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec3 Color;"
    "in vec2 Texcoord;"
    "out vec4 outColor;"
    "uniform sampler2D tex;"
    "void main() {"
    "   outColor = texture(tex, Texcoord) * vec4(Color, 1.0);"
    // "   outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);"
    //"   outColor = texture(tex, Texcoord);"
     "}";
}

GLRenderer::~GLRenderer()
{
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
}

void GLRenderer::initializeGL()
{
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if (err != GLEW_OK)
{
    printf("%s", glewGetErrorString(err));
}

// Create Vertex Array Object
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(tmpdata), tmpdata, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create and compile the vertex shader
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &VertSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

// Create and compile the fragment shader
GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &FragSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);


// Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

// Specify the layout of the vertex data
GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(5 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

// Load texture
GLuint tex;
glGenTextures(1, &tex);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

// Black/white checkerboard
float pixels[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
};
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
}

void GLRenderer::paintGL()
{
    // Clear the screen to black
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
}
```

Comment: Based on symptoms only: can it be the case as solved in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4127918/2564301: "Try adding `glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);`"? (And mind your comments: "Clear the screen to black" is no longer true, presumably for debugging :)

Comment: I don't see a `glUniformi` call anywhere in the code, this call is needed to link the "tex" sampler2D in your shader to bind location 0. (You implicity bind to location 0 by calling glBindTexture without first specifying a location). What you want is to call `glUniformLocation(program, "tex")` and supply the returned value to
`glUniformi(location, 0)`. Try that, may work, im sleepy.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried adding uniform locations no avail.
Aswell as implementing this with glew, I have also re-implemented it with QopenglFunctions Qt's own openGL functionality and get the same result.